# "sie" or "die" when referring to "they"

Tags: english-to-german, personal-pronoun

I am looking for a proper way of saying the following in German:

> Company X told us that **they** have received the documents.

I have been using the following but I tend to think it is not right due to referring Company X with "die".

> Company X hat uns gesagt, dass **die** die Unterlagen erhalten haben.

Comment: It should be "sie", you are completely right.

Comment: Often "die" is colloquially used here but it is more rude and grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @bkausbk Often followed by a "die hat auch einen Namen".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) There should be a comma between "*gesagt*" and "*dass*" because you start a subordinate clause with the word "*dass*".

2) The correct word here is "*sie*".

"*Die*" is sometimes used by people in the street when saying "they". This is done in two contexts:

- People who speak a (strong) dialect instead of official German
- When you point at someone with a finger

(This is also true for many other articles like *der*, *dem*, *den*, ...)

Using "*die*" is often considered to be unfriendly; maybe because the other person feels like you are pointing at him/her with your finger.

I remember some TV soap where a person said something like this: "***Die*** war aber zuhause." Just hearing the word "*die*" you knew: both people don't like each other.

Answer (score 6):

Es kommt darauf an, in welcher stilistischen Umgebung du so etwas sagen möchtest.

In reinem, standardmäßigem Schriftdeutsch würde es heißen

> Firma X hat uns mitgeteilt, dass sie die Unterlagen erhalten hat.
>
> Firma X hat mitgeteilt, dass die Unterlagen angekommen sind.
>
> Unternehmen X hat uns mitgeteilt, dass es die Unterlagen erhalten hat.

In legerer Ausdrucksweise - vorwiegend mündlich - könnte man auch sagen:

> Von Firma X kam die Nachricht, dass sie die Unterlagen erhalten haben.

Sehr untypisch wäre jedoch

> <strike>Firma X hat uns mitgeteilt, dass sie die Unterlagen erhalten haben.</strike>

Dies (Firma im Singular plus "sie" im Plural) ist eine direkte Übertragung aus dem Englischen (Company X told us that they received...), die sich im Deutschen (zum Glück) (noch) nicht eingebürgert hat.

Dein Vorschlag

> Firma X hat und mitgeteilt, dass die die Unterlagen erhalten haben

ist eine irritierende Formulierung. Man denkt sich: Entweder ist der Sprecher in deutscher Ausdrucksweise ungeübt oder die Situation ist eine verzwicktere: 'Firma X teilt uns mit, dass Firma Y ("die"!) die Unterlagen erhalten hat.' Man würde "die" nämlich selbst in legerer Ausdrucksweise nur in Bezug auf einen Dritten bzw. eine Gruppe von Dritten sagen.

Grundsätzlich ist es eine flappsige, eigentlich unhöfliche Ausdrucksweise, über Leute mit "der/die" zu sprechen. Man macht das manchmal, wenn man mit vertrauten Leuten unter sich ist. Aber man sollte es unterbleiben lassen, wenn die angesprochenen Dritten es hören könnten.

Ein flappsiges Gespräch im Krankenhaus:

> A: Hat der Herr Müller heute seine Tabletten schon bekommen?
>
> B: Die Schwester Ilse hat gesagt, dass der die heute schon bekommen hat.
>
> A: Na, frag ihn lieber nochmals selber.
>
> B: Ich hab ihn schon gefragt. Der kann sich aber nicht erinnern. Kennst ihn ja, der vergisst immer gleich alles.

Besser (da auf der höflicheren Seite, sollte Herr Müller zuhören):

> A: Hat Herr Müller heute seine Tabletten schon bekommen?
>
> B: Schwester Ilse hat gesagt, dass **er** die heute schon bekommen hat.
>
> A: Na, frag ihn lieber nochmals selber.
>
> B: Ich hab ihn schon gefragt. **Er** kann sich aber nicht erinnern. Du kennst ihn ja, **er** vergisst Dinge recht schnell.

Comment: In your last example you replaced "der" with "er"; wouldn't it be better to also replace "die" (which refers to "seine Tabletten") with "sie"? Great answer, anyway!

Comment: Yes, actually you are right. In more educated, polite wording it should be "sie" for the pills as well. Probably I left this out because it would be too perfect for a real conversation in a hospital.

Answer (score 2):

*Die* is a demonstrative pronoun here. A finger pointing **to someone else**.

> Die Firma hat uns gesagt, dass **sie** die Unterlagen erhalten haben.

*The company told us **they (the company)/you** have received the documents.*

> Die Firma hat uns gesagt, dass **die** die Unterlagen erhalten haben.

*The company told us **they (others talked about before, neither the company nor you)** have received the documents.*